# Windows Device Driver

Tags: windows, driver

I am trying to write a simple driver. Using this Hello World code:

```
#include <ntddk.h>     
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    DbgPrint("Hello World\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error   1   error -2: "Inf2Cat, signability test failed." Double click to see the tool output.
```

I'm not sure what this means. 
I use the `Win7 Debug` configuration settings.

Comment: I disabled Inf2Cat. Which seems to work. I can compile and build a .sys file. 
Now when I try and load it with OSRLoader, I get `This driver has been blocked from loading`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made similar program and it works perfectly fine for win7 debug config

```
#include "ntddk.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
void DriverUnload( 
PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject) 
{  
DbgPrint("Driver unloading\n"); 
} 
NTSTATUS DriverEntry( 
PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, 
PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) 
{ 
PDEVICE_OBJECT pdo;
DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload; 
DbgPrint("Hello, World\n"); 
return STATUS_SUCCESS; 
}
```

also could check the cat file for any 64 bit decoration error

Comment: Alright, I managed to build a .sys file using your code. I had to disable 'Treat Warnings as Errors'. How would I test this driver?

Comment: Now to test this pseudo driver you need to run this as service

Comment: Make sure to enable test mode if using win7 64bit+ OS
To do so,

install osrloader software and then

give the path for your sys file

then register service

then if you want to see the debug output, open windbg as admin

check kernel debug

and then start service from osrloader

Comment: `This driver has been blocked from loading` I have enabled test mode using bcdedit, yet I still get this message. I'm at a lost.

Comment: did you restart your system after giving bcdedit commands?
you can use dbgView to debug
and to sign your sys file there is a software driver signature enforcement override : dseo

Answer (score 0):

Solutions is project->propeties->ConfigurationProperties->inf2Cat->General->UseLocalTime->Yes